# Using StartActiviytForResult

Tags: android, android-activity, start-activity

I have Three Activity **A**,**B**,**C**.

From **A** activity I send it to **B** using `startActivityforResult` and then from activity **B** I Send it to Activity **C** using `startActivityforResult` but when I came back to activity **A** from all activities with `RESULTOK` than i got no data on activity **A** and every thing refresh on **bluestack** but its working fine on **Samsung** and **Motorola** as I had tested on that.

So I want it to be working on all devices.

I had set my activity orientation to **Portait** statically in all activities.

Code:

Acitivity A:

```
Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(),B.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 1);

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
      String result = data.getStringExtra("imagesreturn");
    }
  }
}
```

Activity B:

```
ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {    
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent i = new Intent(CameraUiActivity.this,  CameraImageTakenActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("image", f.getAbsolutePath());
    startActivityForResult(i, 1);
    // dialog.dismiss();
  }
});

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (requestCode == 1) {
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
      String result = data.getStringExtra("images");
      Intent intent = new Intent();
      intent.putExtra("imagesreturn",result);
      setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);        
      finish();
    }

    if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
      //Write your code if there's no result
      finish();
    }
  }
}
```

Activity C:

```
final String myimage = b.getString("image");
btnsave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {              
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("images",myimage);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);        
    finish();
  }
});
```

Comment: Please show the relevant code.

Comment: okay i will provide it later on

Comment: I take it you have onActivityResult(..) in both Activty A and Activity B?